# Spring @Scheduler Overlap

Tags: spring-scheduled

I have 2 methods to run periodically with spring scheduler, one is with @Scheduled(fixedRate=300000) - for every 5 mins and 
 other is @Scheduled(cron="0 0 0 2 * * ?) - for daily 2 am. We are not using taskScheduler with thread pool so it uses only one thread 
 so there is no overlap.

What I observed is, when 5 mins job taking more time ( say > 30 mins ) its not allowing other @Scheduled job to run. Suppose my 5 mins job started at 1.45 am and it took 45 mins to process, Other cron which suppose to start at 2 am couldn't start because of thread was busy in 5mins job. Is there any settings where other 2 am job will start as soon thread is released. Help us to understand the behavoir of threads in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

By default Spring scheduler provides a single thread for job execution. You can configure a task executor with more than 1 thread and a queue so that even if all threads are busy job is added to the queue and gets picked up as soon as a thread is free.

Following example creates a simple ScheduledThreadPool.

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class Configuration implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar 
     scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
    }
}
```